# Add buttons to the left and right of the searchbar

Tags: ios, search, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller, searchbar

I want a searchbar that has a button on the left of the text field, and on the right. Identical to the searchbar found on the current Alien Blue reddit app.

[image: AlienBlue SearchBar]

So far, the closest thing I have to achieving this is that I have been able to change the text of the "Cancel" button on the right side using this line of code.

```
[self.searchController.searchBar setValue:@"Hello" forKey:@"_cancelButtonText"];
```

But that doesn't really help since I want the right side to open up different search options, not cancel the search.

Help me ____, you're my only hope

Comment: probably you should custom a UISearch with either xib or programming. So that you can set its size and put two button beside it.

Answer (score 1):

Put the effect first

[image]

```
//RWSearchBar.h
#define BarFrame CGRectMake(100, 20, 200, 44)

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface RWSearchBar : UISearchBar

@end

//RWSearchBar.m
#import "RWSearchBar.h"

@implementation RWSearchBar

- (void)layoutSubviews {
    self.frame = BarFrame;
}

@end

//RWViewController.m
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "RWSearchBar.h"

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    RWSearchBar *searchBar = [[RWSearchBar alloc] init];
    [self.view addSubview:searchBar];
    CGRect aFrame = BarFrame;

    UIButton *leftBtn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(aFrame.origin.x - 60, aFrame.origin.y, 60, 44)];
    leftBtn.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    UIButton *rightBtn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(aFrame.origin.x + aFrame.size.width, aFrame.origin.y, 60, 44)];
    rightBtn.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];

    [self.view addSubview:leftBtn];
    [self.view addSubview:rightBtn];
}
```

You can custom more visual effect by yourself.